# How two precedence constraints from different task can goto one task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Please I need help regarding how to resolve two precedence constraint merge to one task. The issue is that the script task check for csv file, if exist run the next task and if it doesn't exist goto the next script task and check if zip file exist, if exist run unzip task then run the loop. If I run the package when csv file do not exist, the zip file check runs and unzip runs and the task stop at in zip but refuse to run the loop. but if csv file exist it ran. How can I resolve the precedent constraint to work when the unzip task execute to run loop.

Comment: You might need to sketch out that flow a little better; any way you can express the logic with code (pseudo code or otherwise)?

Comment: Can you show us how your tasks and constraints are set up? You can have your script tasks set a flag based on .csv existence and .zip existence. Then you can set up conditional constraints that check the value of these flags to determine how to direct the flow of the package.

Comment: @MikeEale it is good to visit the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about asking and accepting answer before asking your first question. also you will get your first "informed" badge after reading the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on one of the precedence constraints linked to the Task you want to execute and check the `Logical Or` option.

[image]

Comment: @MikeEale if it works, you have to accept this answer. Just click on the mark below the voting arrows

Comment: I'm new here and can't find the voting arrows to accept this answer